# Conditional Statement in QML

Tags: json, qt, qml, qqmlapplicationengine

I have a .json file in my project that looks as follows:

```
{
   "ccu3":[
      {
         "PinName":"J1-13",
         "PinDirection":"Input",
         "PinType":"digital",
         "System Function":"Park Lights"
      },
      {
         "PinName":"J1-104",
         "PinDirection":"Input",
         "PinType":"analogue",
         "System Function":"Hydraulic Temp"
      },
      {
         "PinName": "J2-45" , 
         "PinDirection":"Input", 
         "PinType":"tristate", 
         "System Function" : "Auto Greaser Pressure Sw"
     }
   ]
}
```

I can extract "Pin Direction" and "PinType" from .json file as follows:

```
Text
{
    text: jsonLoader.jsonObject["ccu3"][index]["PinDirection"]
    color: "white"
    font.pointSize: 10
}

Text
{
    text: jsonLoader.jsonObject["ccu3"][index]["PinType"]
    color: "white"
    font.pointSize: 10
}
```

If 'PinDirection' is 'output' and 'PinType' is 'digital', I must display the PinName along with the Switch, else if 'PinDirection' is 'output' and 'PinType' is 'analogue', display Pin Name along with the Slider.

How do I make this conditional statement in QML? I'm also using the repeater to call the relevant .qml file for display.

My background is C and just started using QML. I only understand if  else statement

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: How do I handle the conditional statement in QML like if else statement in C? I have to read PinDirection from the json file then decide which qml object (e.g. Switch or Slider) to load.

Comment: I need to be able to scan the json file and read value of PinDirection, if PinDirection is Output and Pintype is analog, I want to use the Slider QML type otherwise use Switch QML type

Comment: You really need to complete your question and add the Slider and Switch to the description. The way your question read is incomplete/ambiguous, since, of course, QML supports Javascript, and your current `if` statement is valid JavaScript. The inclusion of the Slider and Switch components disambiguates the question of how to selectively display a QML component. One "simple" way to implement what you want is to include both Slider and Switch but just assign the `visible` property to positive or negative versions of your conditional respectively.

Comment: Another solution is to assign the `ccu3` subobject to a model and make use of `DelegateChooser` to instantiate the appropriate delegate/component based on "PinDirection" value.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, one solution is to control visibility, e.g.

```
            ColumnLayout {
                visible: modelData.PinDirection === 'output'
                      && modelData.PinType === 'digital'
                Text {
                    text: modelData.PinName
                }
                Switch {
                }
            }
```

Here's a full working example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels
Page {
    id: page
    background: Rectangle { color: "#848895" }
    property var jsonObject: ({
        "ccu3":[
            {
                "PinName":"J1-13",
                "PinDirection":"Input",
                "PinType":"digital",
                "System Function":"Park Lights"
            },
            {
                "PinName":"J1-104",
                "PinDirection":"Input",
                "PinType":"analogue",
                "System Function":"Hydraulic Temp"
            },
            {
                "PinName": "J2-45" , 
                "PinDirection":"Input", 
                "PinType":"tristate", 
                "System Function" : "Auto Greaser Pressure Sw"
            },
            {
                "PinName": "J9-99" , 
                "PinDirection":"Output", 
                "PinType":"tristate", 
                "System Function" : "Test Output"
            }
        ]
    })
    ListView {
        width: 500
        height: 500
        model: jsonObject.ccu3
        delegate: ColumnLayout {
            ColumnLayout {
                visible: modelData.PinDirection === 'output'
                && modelData.PinType === 'digital'
                Text {
                    text: modelData.PinName
                }
                Switch {
                }
            }
            Text {
                text: modelData.PinDirection
            }
            Text {
                text: modelData.PinType
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)